# Celery/Redis same task being executed multiple times in parallel

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have 2 custom tasks (`TaskA` and `TaskB`), both inherit from `celery.Task`. Scheduler launches `TaskA` every now and then, and `TaskA` launches `N` times `TaskB` with different arguments every time. But for some reason, sometimes same `TaskB`, with same arguments, is being executed twice at the same time, and that causes different issues with the database.

```
class TaskA(celery.Task):

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        objects = MyModel.objects.filter(processed=False)\
                                 .values_list('id', flat=True)
        task_b = TaskB()
        for o in objects:
            o.apply_async(args=[o, ])

class TaskB(celery.Task):

    def run(self, obj_id, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=obj_id)
        # do some stuff with obj
```

**Things I've tried**

I tried using `celery.group` in hopes that it will fix such issues, but all I got were errors, saying that `run` takes 2 arguments and none were provided.

This is how I tried to launch `TaskB` using `celery.group`:

```
# somewhere in TaskA
task_b = TaskB()
g = celery.group([task_b.s(id) for id in objects])
g.apply_async()
```

I also tried it like this:

```
# somewhere in TaskA
task_b = TaskB()
g = celery.group([task_b.run(id) for id in objects])
g.apply_async()
```

which executed the tasks right there, before `g.apply_async()`.

**Question**

Does the issue come from how I launch tasks or is it something else? Is it a normal behaviour?

**Additional Info**

On my local machine I run `celery 3.1.13` with `RabbitMQ 3.3.4`, and on server `celery 3.1.13` runs with `Redis 2.8.9`.
On local machine I see no such behaviour, every task is executed once. On server I see anywhere between 1 - 10 such tasks being executed twice in a row.

This is how I run celery on local machine and on server:

```
celery_beat: celery -A proj beat -l info

celery1: celery -A proj worker -Q default -l info --purge -n default_worker -P eventlet -c 50

celery2: celery -A proj worker -Q long -l info --purge -n long_worker -P eventlet -c 200
```

**Workaround that works**

I introduced a lock on `TaskB` based on what arguments it recieved. After about 10 hours of testing, I see what exactly is being executed twice, but the lock prevents collision on database. 
This does solve my issue, but I would still like to understand why is it happening.

Comment: Your code should work fine. I've copied [your code to one file like this](http://pastebin.com/f1gAf4R4) and all tasks has been executed after calling `TaskA().apply_async()`. Could you post your traceback to see where is an issue?

Comment: the traceback comes from the database. `MyModel` has unique constraint on 2 fields. So when the task is run the first time and creates a new object, it's all good, but then same task runs again, and tries to create same object again and throws `IntegrityError`.

Comment: With code which you posted it's impossible to replicate your issue. I think that you could try creating seperate TaskB instances for each task as it could be an issue. Try: `g = celery.group([TaskB().s(id) for id in objects])`

Comment: I tried that too with same results. The code i posted represents pretty close what are my actual tasks doing. I will switch to running celery on redis on my local machine, maybe that will give me better debug info on what is going on.

Comment: You probably want to watch this presentation http://youtu.be/3cyq5DHjymw?t=24m20s

Comment: @AnthonyKong that was actually very easy and straightforward presentation thank you!

Comment: How did you introduce a lock on TaskB? It'd be helpful for people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

Have you set the `fanout_prefix` and `fanout_patterns` as described in the [Using Redis](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#broker-redis) documentation for Celery?  I am using Celery with Redis and I am not experiencing this problem.

Comment: I experienced this same problem, with one task queueing other tasks, and those other tasks being picked up and executed multiple times. Setting the `fanout_prefix` and `fanout_patterns` as described seems to have fixed the issue. Using Celery 3.1.18 and Kombu 3.0.30