# Celery/Django/Redis same task getting executed multiple times

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

In my current project, what I need to do is to get data from 700+ endpoints and then send that data to another 700+ endpoints. My approach is to use Django Celery Redis, Put 70+ endpoints on each worker so that there are approx 10 workers which will retrieve the data and then post the data.

For this, I am using Chord to do the parallel task and then calculate the time it takes.

The problem is that Celery is running the same task multiple times. `task_get_data` is the main method that first gets the list of websites then splits it into groups of 70 each and then calls `task_post_data` using Chord.

In the output below you can see `website_A`, `website_B` etc. multiple times, I have manually checked my data and everything and there is no repetition of websites but when the celery task is submitted, multiple entries are created.

Also, Is there any way to monitor the number of workers and what are they processing?

Below is the code

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','django_backend.settings')

app = Celery('django_backend', backend='redis://localhost:6379', broker='redis://localhost:6379')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
# app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))

def post_data(json_obj, website):
    for items in json_obj:
        md = md + items['data']
    n = 50
    list_of_objects = [md[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(md), n)]
    
    print("Starting to post data using post__data")
    for items in list_of_objects:
        data_details = PostDataDetails()
        data_details.data = items
        post_data_response = ""
        try:
            post_data_response = client.post_data(post_data_details = data_details)
            
            print("Successfully posted data with status code " + str(post_data_response.status) + " for " + website)
        except Exception as e:
           
    return post_data_response.status

def read_from_file():
        with open('./django_backend/data.json') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            # print(data)
        return data

def split_list(l,n):
    website_list = [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
    return website_list


#-----------this is the main method---------
@app.task(bind=True, name="task_get_data")
def task_get_data(self):
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    try:
        website = task_helper.get_data()
        task_helper.write_logs("info", "Successfully read from cache")
    except Exception as e:
        task_helper.write_logs("error", "Error in reading from cache. Error" + str(e))
  
    website_list_chunks = split_list(list(website.keys()),70)
    callback = get_time_difference.s(start_time)

    try:
        task_helper.write_logs("info", "Starting the task_post_poller_data task to post  data")
        header = [task_post_data.s(website_list) for website_list in website_list_chunks]
        result = chord(header)(callback)
        print(result)
        task_helper.write_logs("info", "Successfully completed the task to post  data")
    except Exception as e:
        task_helper.write_logs("error", "Error in creating task_post_data task. Error" + str(e))


@app.task(bind=True, name="task_post_data")
def task_post_data(self,website_list=None) -> dict:
    json_object_response = True
    post_data_response = None
    for website in website_list:
        if json_object_response:
            file_data = read_from_file()
            try:
                post_data_response = post_data(file_data, website)
                # pass
            except Exception as e:
                print("error", "Error in creating task_post_poller_data task. Error" + str(e))
    return post_data_response
```

I am running the code using
`celery -A django_backend worker -l debug --purge` command and I am submitting the task using this command

```
python manage.py shell
>>>from django_backend.tasks import task_get_data
>>>task_get_data.delay()
```

Below is the output from console

```
[2021-07-20 19:54:54,789: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_D
[2021-07-20 19:54:54,835: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-5] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_E
[2021-07-20 19:54:54,840: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_B
[2021-07-20 19:54:54,843: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_A
[2021-07-20 19:54:54,882: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-6] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_P
[2021-07-20 19:54:54,891: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_I
[2021-07-20 19:54:54,895: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_R
[2021-07-20 19:54:55,021: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_D
[2021-07-20 19:54:55,025: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_C
[2021-07-20 19:54:55,073: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_B
[2021-07-20 19:54:55,086: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Successfully posted  data with status code 200 for  website_A
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is one of the known issue with Celery and Redis. In one of my project I used to assign a unique identifier in cache for each task and then in the beginning of the task just check if the key already exist or not. You can write a context manager for such thing. Something like this

```py
@contextmanager
def task_lock(lock_id, oid, lock_expire_seconds=600, unlock_after_finish=False):
    """
    Be sure that task runs only once
    :param lock_id: unique id of task
    :param oid: unique id of current job (needs for debug only)
    :param lock_expire_seconds: task will be unlocked in x seconds
    :param unlock_after_finish: bool, allow run next task after finish of current one
    """
    timeout_at = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=lock_expire_seconds)
    oid = "{}-{}".format(os.environ.get("HOSTNAME", ""), oid)
    # cache.add fails if the key already exists
    status = cache.add(lock_id, oid, lock_expire_seconds)
    try:
        yield status
    finally:
        # cache delete is very slow, but we have to use it to take
        # advantage of using add() for atomic locking
        if unlock_after_finish and datetime.utcnow() < timeout_at:
            # don't release the lock if we exceeded the timeout
            # to lessen the chance of releasing an expired lock
            # owned by someone else.
            cache.delete(lock_id)
```

And then in your task code you can do

```py
def some_task():
    with task_lock("task-lcok", current_time, lock_expire_seconds=10) as acquired:
        if acquired:
            # do something
```

Otherwise, there are some otherthings in the configuration that you can play with. For example check these answers.

1. [Celery is rerunning long running completed tasks over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873407/5084737)
2. [Github issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4400)
3. [Celery/Redis same task being executed multiple times in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320531/5084737)

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, can you please show me how I can use this with Chord or Group?

Comment: I am not sure how to use it with Group or Chord, but I have edited my answer with how I used it. I hope that will help or give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code helped. What I did was to create another task where I would only do the post to websites part and I did call that function inside the with loop.

Comment: It is unclear as to what object your 'cache' represents and what the 'add' function does.

Comment: Its from 'from django.core.cache import cache' as I read from documentation here https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time . Also it would help if we could see what the 'current_time' object passed for 'oid' is here, Im going to test with a regular 'datetime' object and see if you were expecting the string conversion in your oid format line. It doesnt seem like 'oid' matters for the logic though.